# Multiple hive nodes in a cluster?

Tags: hadoop, hive

What is the use of having multiple hive nodes in a cluster as hive just acts a query engine over Hadoop

It can be installed in one of our client node, right ?

i tried reading docs but there was no information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metastore and HiveServer2 are two different nodes already.

Beyond that, the answer is simply for failover / high-availability, typically behind a load-balancer like HAProxy / Nginx, and using Zookeeper for a client quorum.

None of these should be on client nodes, no, only `beeline` / JDBC drivers are needed on client machines.